# Mapping Identity value into DTO from Entityframework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, pass-by-value

I have method that do a bulk insertion from my DTOCollection it has 3 level of looping.

```
public List<FirstCollectionDTO> BulkInsert(List<FirstCollectionDTO> collection)
    {
        using (var db = new DemoEntities())
        {
            //Setting Auto Detech Changes false when starting loop
            db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

            //Looping start
            collection.ForEach(myitem =>
                {
                    myitem.SecondCollection.ForEach(secondLevel =>
                        {
                                 //Some Operation Over here


                            secondLevel.ThirdCollection.ForEach(thirdItem =>
                                {
                                    var myEntity= new MyTable()
                                    {
                                        Level=thirdItem.Name,
                                        Method=thirdItem.Method,
                                      Representation=thirdItem.Representation,
                                    };

                                    var insertedItem = db.MyTable.Add(myEntity);

                                    //Setting the reference of id to the 
                                    //DTO after the save changes. 
                                    //This seems always 0 as it this time
                                    // it have no id only after save changes the id be passed into InsertedItem , I have to pass the reference to myDTO also
                                    thirdItem.Id = insertedItem.Id;
                                });
                        });
                });

            //Setting Auto Detech Changes true when starting loop
            db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;

            // Here I save my changes
            db.SaveChanges();

            return collection;
        }
    }
```

If the INSERT operation succeeds, server-generated values are written back. so how would i get this value into my DTO also.

**How would I get the Id of the inserted object after saving the changes, I need to maintain the relation the of 3 level collection even though**

Comment: The values are assigned and read back into the entities during `SaveChanges`, so you can't know them before that.

Comment: @GertArnold Is there any way I can get id after the save changes and to maintain the relation of 3 levels.

Comment: `thirdItem` could have a property `MyTable`, containing the entity object, so `thirdItem.Id` could return the entity's Id.

Comment: @GertArnold, `ThirdItem` is DTO object, i would prefer to avoid EF reference from DTO

Comment: Then use an interface (for the EF class) or build a dictionary of DTO/Entity pairs during the process.

Comment: @GertArnold yes, How about adding them into anonymous list and reassign to dto on the return .

Something like this `var anonymousprojectList = (new[] { new { a= 0, b= 0, object= new MyTable() } }).ToList();`

Add when the document is added and reassign to DTO after the save changes

Comment: Same idea. Whatever suits you.

Answer (score 0):

```
//To get the inserted id 
var anonymousprojectList = (new[] { new { FirstCollectionId= 0, SecondCollectionId= 0, ThirdObject= new Document() } }).ToList();


using (var db = new DemoEntities())
    {
        //Setting Auto Detech Changes false when starting loop
        db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

        //Looping start
        collection.ForEach(myitem =>
            {
                myitem.SecondCollection.ForEach(secondLevel =>
                    {
                             //Some Operation Over here


                        secondLevel.ThirdCollection.ForEach(thirdItem =>
                            {
                                var myEntity= new MyTable()
                                {
                                    Level=thirdItem.Name,
                                    Method=thirdItem.Method,
                                  Representation=thirdItem.Representation,
                                };

                                var insertedItem = db.MyTable.Add(myEntity);

                                //Setting the reference of id to the 
                                //DTO after the save changes. 
                                //This seems always 0 as it this time
                                // it have no id only after save changes the id be passed into InsertedItem , I have to pass the reference to myDTO also
                                using (var db = new DemoEntities())
    {
        //Setting Auto Detech Changes false when starting loop
        db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

        //Looping start
        collection.ForEach(myitem =>
            {
                myitem.SecondCollection.ForEach(secondLevel =>
                    {
                             //Some Operation Over here


                        secondLevel.ThirdCollection.ForEach(thirdItem =>
                            {
                                var myEntity= new MyTable()
                                {
                                    Level=thirdItem.Name,
                                    Method=thirdItem.Method,
                                  Representation=thirdItem.Representation,
                                };

                                var insertedItem = db.MyTable.Add(myEntity);

                                //Setting the reference of id to the 
                                //DTO after the save changes. 
                                //This seems always 0 as it this time
                                // it have no id only after save changes the id be passed into InsertedItem , I have to pass the reference to myDTO also
                                anonymousprojectList.Add(new {FirstCollectionID = myItem.Od,SecondCollectionId=secondLevel.Id,ThirdObject = insertedItem});
                            });
                    });
            });

        //Setting Auto Detech Changes true when starting loop
        db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;

        // Here I save my changes
        db.SaveChanges();

                            });
                    });
            });

        //Setting Auto Detech Changes true when starting loop
        db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;

        // Here I save my changes
        db.SaveChanges();
   }
       // Loop through the anonymous collection and assign to the input collection itself 
       //Skip header item
       anonymousprojectList.Skip(1).ToList().ForEach(object=>
        {
          //Loop through the three level and assign the value

          //Assign the value
          ThirdlevelItem.Id = ThirdObject.Id) 

        });

return collection
```